# cpp template<> spacing using clang-format 3.6 not working as expected

Tags: c++, templates, vim, clang-format

I am using the `clang-format version 3.6 on Fedora 21` inside `vim` using the `clang-format.py` for `cpp` code. The code looks as expected except for the template definitions. The code for `template<typename T>`  is being changed to `template <typename T>` The only option that looked relatively close 
`ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList` which I set to false but it still is putting the space between the word template and the angle bracket. Does anyone have any idea on how to prevent this from inserting the space between the word template and the angle bracket?

Comment: Why would you want to prevent that? Don't you find `template <typename T>` more legible than `template<typename T>` or even `template< typename T >`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the time of writing (Dec 2015) you can't.  See [this bug report](http://reviews.llvm.org/D10807) where they say they won't fix it.